# C Code Pointer Puzzle

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, 64-bit, puzzle

I'm looking at some code a classmate posted and it has been simplified for the sake of this example:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0x4142;
    char * a = (char *) &n;

    char * b1 = (((char *) &n) + 1);
    char * b2 = (((int) &n) + 1);

    printf("B1 Points to 0x%x - B2 Points to 0x%x\n", b1, b2);

    printf("A Info - 0x%x - %c\n", a, *a);
    printf("B1 Info - 0x%x - %c\n", b1, *b1);
    printf("B2 Info - 0x%x - %c\n", b2, *b2);

   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
B1 Points to 0xcfefb03d - B2 Points to 0xcfefb03d
A Info - 0xcfefb03c - B
B1 Info - 0xcfefb03d - A
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It segmentation faults when trying to print out b2. Whereas I think the output should include the following line instead of seg faulting:

```
B2 Info - 0xcfefb03d - A
```

Why is this the case? b1 and b2 are both char*, and they both point to the same address. This is on a 64bit machine where sizeof(char*) == 8 and sizeof(int) == 4 if that matters.

Comment: I dont see an error in the program: http://codepad.org/VU8upOdl

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue pointed out by my classmate. There is no problem in codepad, but it segfaults on a 64bit computer. Both on OS X 10.7 64bit and on Ubuntu Linux 64 bit.

Comment: `%x` interprets its argument as `unsigned int` (C11 §7.21.6.1.8). To print a pointer, you're supposed to use `%p`.

Comment: Okay, yeah that explains everything... Face Palm... Thanks

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Point Noted. Didn't realize the correct etiquette about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it segfaults on a 64bit computer

The likely reason is that, on your platform, pointers are 64-bit and ints are 32-bit. Thus when you cast the pointer to `int`, you lose information.

My compiler specifically warns about this:

```
test.c:7:19: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

This is easy to see using the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char *s = "";
   printf("%p %p\n", s, (char*)(int)s);
   return 0;
}
```

On my computer, this prints two different addresses (the second has its top bits chopped off).

> what I don't quite understand is that both b1 and b2 are char*, and they both point to the same address

Actually, they don't point to the same address. Your `printf()` format specifiers are all wrong. The first `printf()` should be:

```
printf("B1 Points to %p - B2 Points to %p\n", b1, b2);
```

When you run this, you'll see that the addresses differ.

Comment: Loss of information makes sense, but what I don't quite understand is that both b1 and b2 are char*, and they both point to the same address. I must be missing something still.

Comment: @tigger: I've added an explanation to the answer. In a nutshell, they *appear* the same because your `printf()` format specifiers are wrong. In fact, the addresses are different.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kicking myself for not realizing that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`(int)&n` may truncate the address of `n` to how many bits there are in `int`, IOW, if the pointer size is longer than the size of int (which is often the case on 64-bit CPUs), you get a bogus, truncated address/pointer that you cannot dereference safely.

Comment: Truncation makes sense, but what I don't understand is that b1 and b2 are both char*, and they both point to the same address.

Comment: Truncation means they *don't* point to the same address. One address has a bunch of zeros at the top.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, since an `int` is 4 bytes, the value of `&n` is truncated when you cast it and try to assign it to `b2`. To treat pointer values as integers, use `uintptr_t`, an unsigned integer type that can safely store a pointer regardless of the platform capacity:

```
char * b2 = (((int) &n) + 1);
```

should be:

```
char * b2 = ((uintptr_t) &n) + 1;
```